# WebScraping a changing webpage search results?

Tags: pandas, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to get data from a search result but every time I try to use a specific link to give to Beautiful Soup I get errors and I think it is because the webpage isn't the same every time you visit it? I'm not exactly sure what this is called to even search so any help would be appreciated.

This is the link to the search results. But when you go to visit it unless you've already made a search it won't show up the results.
https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Portal/Home/WorkspaceMode?p=0

instead, if you copy and paste it will take you to this page to make a search.
https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Portal/ and then you have to click smart search.

So for simplicity's sake, let's say we search for "Robinson" and I need to take the table data and export it to an excel file. I cant give beautiful soup a link because it isn't valid I believe? How would I go about this challenge?

Even pulling the tables up with a simple view table doesn't give any info about the data from our search of "Robinson" such as Case Number or File Date to create a pandas data frame.

//EDIT//
so far thanks to @Arundeep Chohan
This is what I've got. Huge Shout out for the awesome help!

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.implicitly_wait(20) # gives an implicit wait for 20 seconds

driver.get("https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Portal/Home/Dashboard/29")

search_box = driver.find_element_by_id("caseCriteria_SearchCriteria")
search_box.send_keys("Robinson")

#Code to complete captchas
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe[name^='a-'][src^='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/anchor?']")))
WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@id='recaptcha-anchor']"))).click()

driver.switch_to.default_content() #necessary to switch out of iframe element for submit button

time.sleep(5) #gives time to click submit to results
submit_box = driver.find_element_by_id("btnSSSubmit").click()

time.sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,'html.parser')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
options = Options()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
wait=WebDriverWait(driver,10)
driver.get('https://www.clarkcountycourts.us/Portal/')

wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a.portlet-buttons"))).click()
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"input#caseCriteria_SearchCriteria"))).send_keys("Robinson")
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[@title='reCAPTCHA']")))
elem=wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div.recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", elem)
driver.switch_to.default_content()
x = input("Waiting for recaptcha done")
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@id='btnSSSubmit'])[1]"))).click()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
print(df)
```

Should be the minimum to get to your page if you want to know.There's an iframe to deal and the spinner to deal with.  After this just use pandas to grab the table.

(edit): They added a recaptcha properly so add a solver where I added my pause input.

Import:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

Outputs:

```
Waiting for manual date to be entered. Enter YES when done.
  Unnamed: 0_level_0  ...                                      Date of Birth
         Case Number  ...                                          File Date
         Case Number  ...                                          File Date
0                NaN  ...                                                NaN
1                NaN  ...  Cases (1)  Case NumberStyle / DefendantFile Da...
2        Case Number  ...                                          File Date
3          08A575873  ...                                         11/17/2008
4                NaN  ...                                                NaN
5                NaN  ...  Cases (1)  Case NumberStyle / DefendantFile Da...
6        Case Number  ...                                          File Date
7          08A575874  ...                                         11/17/2008
```

Comment: Wow, awesome greatly appreciate the time and effort to help! So would I use something like this to grab data from table?                                                                             soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

tbl = soup.findAll("table")
dfs = pd.read_html(str(tbl))
df = dfs[0]

Comment: No problem when you get it running and need more help just ask away.

Comment: You can pass the source into beautifulsoup. soup=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source). From there you can just use those methods.

Comment: Seems they added something to the recaptcha. Might need to add one of the recaptcha solvers before you hit submit.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for!  I couldn't have done it without your help. I truly am grateful.  One last question is there a way to specify only the Case Number and File Date to be displayed? If not you've been more than helpful!!

Comment: There should  be you could list the columns for somebody more familar with pandas though.